# Regular expression to remove a parameter from url

Tags: php, regex, url

I have an url which looks like page.php?stuff=stuff&stuff=stuff&order=sometext&page=number

and I want to remove the "order=sometext" part. I'm using this php code :

```
        $link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $re = "/&order=/";
        $link = preg_replace($re, "", $link);
```

And I'm looking for the correct pattern that should be $re to clear the "order=sometext" from the url. 
The "&page=number" part has to be kept when present, but isn't always there.
Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Yeah thanks, I just mistyped when posting my question.

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be

```
(&|\?)order=[^&]+
```

`(&|\?)`: the order could be first in the list, so we are removing either & or ?.

Comment: Oh. What does the (&|\?) change ?

Comment: In my situtation it will never be first but thanks anyway for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I made it work using `/&order=[^&]*/`. :)